# How to save M2M Field in a formset when commit=False

Tags: django

```
deals_formset_factory = modelformset_factory(Deal, form=DealCForm, extra=1)    
attached_deals_formset = deals_formset_factory(request.POST, prefix='deals')
```

Since some fields of my `Deal` model are not shown in the form and hence can't be set by the user (but the M2M field is shown and can be set by the user), I can't just do a

```
for fm in attached_deals_formset:                
    if fm.has_changed(): 
       fm.save()
```

since it would break.

So theoretically the idea in such situations is to do

```
deal = fm.save(commit=False)
...
deal.save()
```

but this doesn't save my M2M field inside deal. The Through table remains untouched.  What is the best approach to solve this?

```
class Deal(models.Model):            
    deal_id             = UUIDField()
    ....
    sales_item          = models.ManyToManyField(SalesItem)
```

Comment: have you tried overriding the form's save() method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution, there is no need to override the save method.

> Another side effect of using commit=False is seen when your model has
>   a many-to-many relation with another model. If your model has a
>   many-to-many relation and you specify commit=False when you save a
>   form, Django cannot immediately save the form data for the
>   many-to-many relation. This is because it isn't possible to save
>   many-to-many data for an instance until the instance exists in the
>   database.
>
> To work around this problem, every time you save a form using
>   commit=False, Django adds a save_m2m() method to your ModelForm
>   subclass. After you've manually saved the instance produced by the
>   form, you can invoke save_m2m() to save the many-to-many form data

[Source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method)

After deal.save() simply:

```
fm.save_m2m()
```